# PWA - Como passar parâmetros para outra página estando offiline?

Tags: javascript, query, get, pwa, service-worker

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo PWA que vai funcionar principalmente no modo offiline, já criei e implementei praticamente tudo, indexedDB, service-worker, etc... Estou tentando passar algunas parâmetros para outro página usando o método GET e para ler os valores em java script estou usando essa função:

Por exemplo, a página indexed.php chama a página parameters.php com alguns parâmetros:

```
function $_GET()
{
    var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
    var GET = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var temp = parts[i].split("=");
        GET[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]); 
    }

    return GET;
}
```

E a página parameters.php lê esse valores e executa algumas ações.

```
window.location.href = "/parameters.php?id=1";
```

O problema aparece quando eu estou offiline e tento carregar essas páginas, dá errado pq as URL's não são as mesmas das que foram pro cache. Já tentei diversas maneiras de ignorar as query strings mas sem sucesso. Gostaria de saber se existe algumas outra alternativa de fazer isso, e quais são os métodos mais recomendados de passar parâmetros para outras páginas estando offiline.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/436788/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que eu consegui contornar isso é passando os parâmetros via `hash`

Ex: /pagina/#page=livro&id=1

```
function get_hash() {
    var GET = {};
    try {
        var hash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
        var partes = hash.split('&');
        partes.forEach(function (parte) {
            if (parte != '') {
                var chaveValor = parte.split('=');
                GET[chaveValor[0]] = chaveValor[1];
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    return GET;
}
```

Com isso vc consegue montar a requisição para o servidor com os dados fornecidos via parâmetros. Caso esteja offline resgata as informações do indexDb